# cannot get value when I click the auto select

Tags: html

code is very simple:

```html
<form method="get" action="/category" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <input id="categoryName" class="form-control" placeholder="category name" name="categoryName">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return checkInput()">add</button>
</form>
```

Problem is after I click the input, then chrome shows a select list which has input history below it. When I choose one of them and submit, I cannot get the value. I am a new student in web,  anyone can help?

detail is like this picture:
[image]

Comment: This is actually a "feature" of chrome. Since it's a password field, you can't access its value from JavaScript. Read the second answer on the marked duplicate to find more.

Comment: I'm not get it from js but finally I found out it's the browser's cache prevent the form's action being sent to server.